# Silverlight ChildWindow styling

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I've set some properties in my App.xaml to implicitly style all of the ChildWindows in my app, but it doesn't seem to work.

I can set an implicit global style for *any* other type of control and it works, but when I set styles for ChildWindows, it literally changes nothing.

Here is an example of the XAML that doesn't work:

```
<Style TargetType="controls:ChildWindow">
    <Setter Property="OverlayOpacity" Value="0" />
</Style>
```

Shouldn't this just work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that impilict styles only apply to controls of the specific type referenced by the TargetType.  They do **not** apply to derived types of the `TargetType`.

Since you will never be creating an instance of `ChildWindow` but will be creating only derived types of `ChildWindow` the style does not apply.

For such a small variation you might as well just include `OverlayOpacity="0"` in the Xaml of your child windows.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. In any case, I've corrected my problem by giving the ChildWindow style tag a key, then I just explicitly reference the style for each ChildWindow in my app.